# Disable/enable 3g using app

Tags: android

I am making an application based on Network connectivity.
   I want to toggle(enable/disable) 3g connection from inside the app, Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

// check isNetAvailable and pass boolean as if you need 3g or not

```
ConnectivityManager connectivityManager;
    NetworkInfo wifiInfo, mobileInfo;


public Boolean isNetAvailable(Context con, boolean is3gOn)
{

    try{
        connectivityManager = (ConnectivityManager) con.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        wifiInfo = connectivityManager.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI);
        mobileInfo = connectivityManager.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE);   

        if(wifiInfo.isConnected())
        {
            return true;
        }

        if(is3gOn){
            return mobileInfo.isConnected();
        }


    }
    catch(Exception e){
       e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return false;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply but I want to disable the 3G network if it is enable how to do that?